# Is there a way to force the coefficient of the independent variable to be a positive coefficient in the linear regression model used in R?

Tags: r, lm

In lm(y ~ x1 + x2+ x3 +...+ xn) , not all independent variables are positive.
For example, we know that x1 to x5 must have positive coefficients and x6 to x10 must have negative coefficients.
However, when lm(y ~ x1 + x2+ x3 +...+ x10) is performed using R, some of x1 ~ x5 have negative coefficients and some of x6 ~ x10 have positive coefficients. is the data analysis result.
I want to control this using a linear regression method, is there any good way?

Comment: This sounds like Simpson's paradox!

Comment: have you tried what's in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644856/r-optim-fitting-parameter-limits

Answer (score 2):

### Constraints

Possibilities include using:

1. nls with algorithm = "port" in which case upper and lower bounds can be specified.
2. nnnpls in the nnls package which supports upper and lower 0 bounds or use nnls in the same package if all coefficients should be non-negative.
3. bvls (bounded value least squares) in the bvls package and specify the bounds.
4. there is an example of performing non-negative least squares in the vignette of the CVXR package.
5. reformulate it as a quadratic programming problem (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares) for the formulation) and use quadprog package.
6. nnls in the limSolve package.  Negate the columns that should have negative coefficients to convert it to a non-negative least squares problem.

These packages mostly do not have a formula interface but instead require that a model matrix and dependent variable be passed as separate arguments.  If df is a data frame containing the data and if the first column is the dependent variable then the model matrix can be calculated using:

```
A <- model.matrix(~., df[-1])
```

and the dependent variable is

```
df[[1]]
```

### Penalties

Another approach is to add a penalty to the least squares objective function, i.e. the objective function becomes the sum of the squares of the residuals plus one or more additional terms that are functions of the coefficients and tuning parameters.  Although doing this does not impose any hard constraints to guarantee the desired signs it may result in the correct signs anyways.  This is particularly useful if the problem is ill conditioned or if there are more predictors than observations.

1. linearRidge in the ridge package will minimize the sum of the square of the residuals plus a penalty equal to lambda times the sum of the squares of the coefficients.  lambda is a scalar tuning parameter which the software can automatically determine. It reduces to least squares when lambda is 0. The software has a formula method which along with the automatic tuning makes it particularly easy to use.
2. glmnet adds penalty terms containing two tuning parameters.  It  includes least squares and ridge regression as a special cases. It also supports bounds on the coefficients. There are facilities to automatically set the two tuning parameters but it does not have a formula method and the procedure is not as straight forward as in the ridge package.  Read the vignettes that come with it for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The sign of a coefficient may change depending upon its correlation with other coefficients. As @TarJae noted, this seems like an example of (or counterpart to?) Simpson's Paradox, which describes cases where the sign of a correlation might reverse depending on if we condition on another variable.

Here's a concrete example in which I've made two independent variables, `x1` and `x2`, which are both highly correlated to `y`, but when they are combined the coefficient for `x2` reverses sign:

```
# specially chosen seed; most seeds' result isn't as dramatic
set.seed(410)    
df1 <- data.frame(y  = 1:10,
                  x1 = rnorm(10, 1:10),
                  x2 = rnorm(10, 1:10))
lm(y ~ ., df1)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = df1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
    -0.2634       1.3990      -0.4792
```

This result is not incorrect, but arises here (I think) because the prediction errors from `x1` happen to be correlated with the prediction errors from `x2`, such that a better prediction is created by *subtracting* some of `x2`.

EDIT, additional analysis:

The more independent series you have, the more likely you are to see this phenomenon arise. For my example with just two series, only 2.4% of the integer seeds from 1 to 1000 produce this phenomenon, where one of the series produces a negative regression coefficient. This increases to 16% with three series, 64% of the time with five series, and 99.9% of the time with 10 series.

Answer (score 0):

1- one way is to define an optimization program and minimize the mean square error by constraints and limits. (nlminb, optim, etc.)
2- Another one is using a library called "lavaan" as follow:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96245/linear-regression-with-upper-and-or-lower-limits-in-r